# Compare two different type of ArrayLists to find common data

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, compare

I have two ArrayLists. Arraylist one stores objects which contains different attributes whose one of them is an integer arraylist.

Arraylist two is an integer arraylist. I want to compare Arraylist two with the integer arraylist that is being stored in arraylist one. To make it easier for you to understand:

ArrayList1 :

- Attribute 1
- Attribute 2
- Integer Arraylist

ArrayList2/Integer Arraylist

I have been trying for a few hours to do this but was not successful. This is my idea:

I have these two ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<LottoTicket> ticketList = new ArrayList<>(); //ArrayList 1

ArrayList<Integer> drawNums = new ArrayList(); //ArrayList 2
```

Now ArrayList 1 stores object LotteryTicket which have an integer ArrayList called 'set' which stores 5 numbers for the lottery.

Here is my idea to compare the 'set' arraylist to the drawNums arraylist:

```
for(LottoTicket l : ticketList)
{        
  if(l.getSet().contains(drawNums.get(1)))
  {
     System.out.println("1 number matches");
  } 
  else 
  {
     System.out.println("No matches");
  }
}
```

But this does not seem to be a good idea! Any help would be greatly appreciated  & I hope this will also help others!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the common items of the two `Collection`(s). You could [`List.retainAll(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) which *removes from this list all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection* and something like,

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(l.getSet());
al.retainAll(drawNums);
System.out.printf("%d number(s) match.%n", al.size());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But does this need to be in the foreach loop where I am referencing every ticket in the ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, in order to call `l.getSet()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for specific *positions* in the drawn numbers list, you should just check whether the list `contains` the numbers picked by the player -- after all, the order of the numbers should not matter. Then, just `count` the numbers that are contained.

Also, you can turn the `List`s into `Set`s to speed up the lookup (although this should not matter much for only five numbers).

```
Set<Integer> numsAsSet = new HashSet<>(drawNums);
for (LottoTicket ticket : ticketList) {
    long matches = ticket.getSet().stream()
                                  .filter(x -> numsAsSet.contains(x))
                                  .count();
    System.out.println("Number of matches: " + matches);
}
```